# Ruby on rails - Inline condition with if, elseif & if conditions

Tags: ruby

In my application every post that is submitted by users will to be *approved* or *denied*. I have a `Post` model and in my `posts` table, I have columns: `approved` & `denied` and both of them are `boolean`.

*In my view I do:*

```
= is_true?(post.approved)? 'APPROVED' : 'PENDING'
```

*NB: `is_true?` is a helper I have in my `ApplicationHelper`*

```
def is_true?(object)
  object == true
end
```

As the code says, if post has been `approved`, it will be *APPROVED*, otherwise is *PENDING*. This works fine, but I don't how to add the *DENIED* in my inline condition.

So basically **IF** post is approved it will be *APPROVED*, **ELSE IF** post has nor been approved or denied it will be *PENDING* & **IF** post has been denied it will be *DENIED*.

I know I can write the condition in my view, but the code becomes ugly and I am fan of `inline conditions` and clean way.

How can I make it clean?

Comment: You wrote that "every post ... will ... be approved or denied". Then you suggest that there are posts that are neither approved nor denied. That is a contradiction.

Comment: @sawa Next time read the question first correctly before voting it down! A post is either *approved* or *denied* & while a post has not be checked for approval or denial, it would be pending. dont just go around and give your down votes because you dont understand the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your fields are boolean already, there's no need of a helper for redundant comparisons..

You can directly do..

```
post.approved? ? 'APPROVED' : post.denied? ? 'DENIED' : 'PENDING'
```

That's a one liner which will work, short story long, which can go to your model and call it from the view..as one liners are confusing sometimes..

```
def status
  if approved?
    'APPROVED'
  elsif denied?
    'DENIED'
  else
    'PENDING'
  end
end
```

From view,

```
post.status
```

**UPDATE**

as per the comments, OP has these fields in multiple models, writing a helper would make it more *DRY* as

```
def status_of(object)
  if object.approved?
    'APPROVED'
  elsif object.denied?
    'DENIED'
  else
    'PENDING'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Farhan for your answer and thanks for pointing out the `helper` functionality :) Appreciate it

Comment: only one question. where `def status` to any other place other then one `model` so I can reuse it for my other models as well? All of them has `approved` & `denied` :)

Comment: If that's the case then you can move it to helper and pass the model object as argument (similar to what you have posted in question) just avoid `== true` check..

Comment: okei Thanks man :) if you would like, you can add the helper to answer, i think many would like the reuse function :)